# why background animation increase its speed when scrolling

Tags: css, animation

I use css animation to animate a background in my website.

you can check the animation here:
http://pce-fet.com/?page=members

the problem is, when scrolling to bottom more and more, the animation speed increase more and more !

I don't know why this is happening, it suppose to keep the speed constant !

the css animation code:

```
.AnimBG { background: url(../common/skyBG.jpg) repeat;animation: 50s linear animateBackground infinite; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 0 0; background-size: 1365px 677px;}

@keyframes animateBackground {
    0% {background-position: 0 0; background-size: 1365px 677px; }
    50% {background-size: 2047px 1015px;background-position: -200px 338px;}
    100% {background-position: 0 677px;background-size: 1365px 677px;}
}
```

NOTE: I've changed the animation in the live website to the following:

```
@keyframes animateBackground {
    0% {background-position: 0 0;  }
    50% {background-position: -200px 338px;}
    100% {background-position: 0 677px;}
}
```

if you want ti see the issue again, you can easily inspect the css and get the `@keyframes` to the old one.

Comment: I would hazarda guess the animation is hinging on the viewport and so when the viewport moves the animation is speeding up/moving to align itself back into sync with the new viewport location on the page. (Sorry, I don't know any workarounds for this )

Comment: Mmmh.. interesting behavior! But why, in your keyframes, do you change also the `background-size`? If you change only `background-position` your animation speed is constant. Is this the effect you want?

Comment: @ReSedano actually I'm increasing the size to about x2 in 50% because i want to give growth effect, but then at 100% i get it back to the origin size to start with the same size at 0% again. But, I don't believe it has anything to do with this weird behavior !

Comment: Really? Have you tried, only for test, to remove `background-position` from your animation? I see that by removing it, the animation gets faster when I move more and more away from the 0 0 point (top left). If you change background-position in `.AnimBg` for example, to 50% (with the animation only on `background-size`) you'll see that now the animation go faster on the top and on bottom of the page: in the center is slower. So, for me it is here the issue: the origin point of background-size when scale from 100% to 200%.

Comment: Drawings more distant from the origin point have to go further than the nearest ones in the same time. So they have to speed up! This is my point of view. :)

Comment: @ReSedano yea you are right, by removing the background-size animation the background-position animate at constant speed. So, any way to solve this issue with this growth effect involve ?